# Git merge - aborting instead of go into merging mode (auto-merging don't start)

Tags: git, merge

I am studying Git now and met problem with merging with conflict:

```
$ git merge master origin/master

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        somefile.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I expected an auto-merging attempt and merging mode after it fails, and see my conflicting file marked with `<<<<<<< HEAD` and such blocks, but this doesn't happen - file stays intact and merging is just aborted.

Is it something wrong with my Git (latest version) configuration?

Comment: did you add and commit somefile.txt before merge?

Comment: Files in the working tree are fragile. Git does not attempt to merge with changed files in the working tree, for safety. Use git-stash, as Colin Schoen's answer points out. (Whereas SVN will happily merge with the working copy, potentially destroying your work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to auto merge you should run

```
git stash
git merge master origin/master
git stash apply
```

Have a look at Nayuki Minase's comment for more details why this is necessary.

Comment: Does git stash / git stash apply in your example means that first we "cut" our changes from working dir and after merging "paste" them back?